# What is the best way to include jQuery, Underscore, and Backbone as AMD modules using require.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, requirejs

I've seen many variations to loading modules which do not support [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) yet, and I would like to know what is the best practice to do so.

Eventually, I would like to write modules like this:

```
module.js:

define(["jQuery", "Underscore", "Backbone"], function($, _, Backbone) {
    ... module code here
}
```

But there are a lot of problems with loading those dependencies using AMD since they are not all AMD compliant.

Comment: What do you mean by AMD? Not the CPU family, right?

Comment: Nope. Asynchronous module definition. Poor choice of TLA I must admit... :)

Comment: A few years back (before the Intel switch, I think), the Mac rumour groups were abuzz with code references to amd. Back then, it was the auto-mount-daemon. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a todo-list boilerplate web app which loads all modules as AMD modules (without loaders).

Check it out:

https://github.com/ronreiter/webapp-boilerplate

Answer (score 2):

Thomas Davis has a better example (imo) for loading jquery/underscore/backbone in his non-updated example. Start by looking at the loader [here](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/blob/gh-pages/examples/modular-backbone/js/libs/backbone/loader.js)

It uses the RequireJS order plugin found [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#order) to load the modules synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/tree/gh-pages/examples/modular-backbone-updated/js) example. It nicely shows how to use backbone along with requirejs. It also shows how you can organize the model, view and collections neatly.

Comment: Looks like the example is an updated version, and not what the tutorial explains in the website. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of RequireJS adds the ability to use NON-AMD JS files.

```
require.config({ 
    'paths': { 
    "underscore": "libs/underscore-min", 
        "backbone": "libs/backbone-min"
    },
    'shim': 
    {
        backbone: {
            'deps': ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            'exports': 'Backbone'
        }
    }   
});
```

Give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

One thing i don't understand about AMD is that looks like it loads necessary js only when it needs but with the demo application it loads all js html css files when you access the app for the first page load.